# At what point and why was the Greek ‘genos’ translated to mean ‘race’? Why is this meaning of ‘race’ only in modern versions?

Tags: greek, new-english-translation

With the current ‘social’ climate, my son and I have been studying out the use of the word ‘race’ in bible translations.  In older translations, this word is used to describe the verb context.  Yet in modern versions (since NASB 95), it is used in reference to groups of individuals based on their appearance/genetics.

At what point and WHY, did biblical translation committees determine the Greek ‘genos’ should be ‘race’ (as in delineating between groups of individuals based on their appearance/genetics)?

I am NOT asking about ‘social justice’. I am asking about the process translation committees use to justify this change in defining ‘genos’

Comment: Could you provide some example verses as a context for the question?

Comment: Do you mean in places like Mark 7:26, 2 Peter 2:9, Phil 3:5, 2 cor 11:26?  The neuter noun simply means "type" or "kind", "race", etc.  This has always been the case.  If you quote one or two texts you want to focus on, I will reopen the question.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Please remember to take the tour to better understand how this site works.  Questions need to be about specific passages of the Bible for Hermeneutics to operate at all.

Comment: BTW - how do you think this word should be translated?